# pip install subdirectory for zip file

Tags: python, pip

When using VCS, pip supports specifying a subdirectory:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#examples.

Is it possible to specify the subdirectory when installing from a zip file?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that's official, but actually works: `pip install file:FULL_PATH.zip#subdirectory=SUB_PATH` - without `file` the whole string is assumed to be a part of file name, including `#subdirectory=`.